# A vectorial geometry problem : $a\cos{\alpha}+b\cos{\beta}+c\cos{\gamma}=0.$

Tags: geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and $O$ the center of circumscribed circle of the triangle. $AB=c, BC=a,CA=b.$  We will denote with $\alpha$ the angle of the vectors : $\vec{AO}$ and $\vec{BC}$ and analogous we will define $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Prove that:

$$a\cos{\alpha}+b\cos{\beta}+c\cos{\gamma}=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $O$ as vectors from an arbitrary origin,
and letting $R$ be the circumradius of the triangle,
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&a\cos{\alpha}+b\cos{\beta}+c\cos{\gamma}\\
&=& 
||B-C||\frac{(O-A)\cdot (C-B)}{||O-A||\,\,||C-B||}
+
||C-A||\frac{(O-B)\cdot (A-C)}{||O-B||\,\, ||A-C||}\\
&&+
||A-B||\frac{(O-C)\cdot (B-A)}{||O-C||\,\, ||B-A||}\\
&=&
\frac{1}{R} ((O-A)\cdot (C-B)+(O-B)\cdot (A-C)+(O-C)\cdot (B-A))\\
&=&
\frac{1}{R} (O\cdot(C-B+A-C+B-A)\\
&&\qquad -(A\cdot(C-B)+B\cdot(A-C)+C\cdot(B-A)))\\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It's not familiar for me this relation : $\displaystyle \cos{\alpha}=\frac{(O-A)(C-B)}{\|O-A\|\|C-B\|}$. Thanks :)

Comment: If $\bf p$ and $\bf q$ are vectors with an angle $\theta$ between them, then ${\bf p}\cdot{\bf q}=||{\bf p}||\,\,||{\bf q}||\,\cos\theta$.